# LoggerName already in use

Tags: nlog, xunit2

So i had this working, ive switched to paket and i guess some versions of dll's have changed.

However I still do not understand the error i am getting.

```
System.ArgumentException : LoggerName already in use
      Parameter name: loggerName
```

my code is basically exactly as it is on here

http://www.tomdupont.net/2015/06/capture-xunit-test-output-with-nlog-and.html

```
public class NLogTests : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public NLogTests(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
    {
        _logger = outputHelper.GetNLogLogger();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _logger.RemoveTestOutputHelper();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Hello()
    {
        _logger.Trace("World Trace");
        _logger.Debug("World Debug");
        _logger.Warn("World Warn");
        _logger.Error("World Error");
    }
}
```

and config

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  throwExceptions="true">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="xunit.NLog" />
  </extensions>
  <targets async="false">
    <target xsi:type="TestOutput"
      layout="${time}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
      name="Test" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="Test" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

The `GetNLogLogger` method has an overload that takes a logger name and a bool for incremental suffixes. Using these does not help.

I am really confused.

stacktrace:

```
System.ArgumentException
LoggerName already in use
Parameter name: loggerName
   at Xunit.NLog.Targets.TestOutputTarget.Add(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, String loggerName)
   at Xunit.NLog.Helpers.TestOutputHelpers.AddTestOutputHelper(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, String loggerName, Boolean addNumericSuffix)
   at Xunit.NLogTestOutputExtensions.GetNLogLogger(ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, String loggerName, Boolean addNumericSuffix)
   at ProjectRake.BusinessLogic.Spec.TautologiesToVerifyNLogOutput..ctor(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper) in M:\programming\ProjectRake\src\server\ProjectRake.BusinessLogic.Spec\TautologiesToVerifyNLogOutput.cs:line 19
```

edit:
have downgraded all xunit stuff to 2.1.0, same issue.

Comment: do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: libary: https://github.com/tdupont750/xunit.NLog

Answer (score 0):

`outputHelper.GetNLogLogger();` is calling `AddTestOutputHelper("")`

I guess it only works if you call it once.

You can use `outputHelper.GetNLogLogger("myname");` or `outputHelper.GetNLogLogger(typeof(NLogTests).Name);`

Comment: As i said, i have tried these overloads. This test is only being run once and so it wouldn't seem like its already set it.

Comment: or to be clear, i can comment out all other tests bar this one and still get the rror